# Checking SAGA version from a python plugin in QGIS 3.4.0

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I use QGIS 3.4.0 on Windows and I want to verify SAGA version with  `processing.algs.saga.SagaUtils.getSagaInstalledVersion()`. But I get an error:
`module 'processing' has no attribute 'algs'`

This was running on 3.2.0

Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a combination of issues - QGIS 3.4 is now using Python 3.7, and the SAGA distribution on OSGeo4W is now (2018/10) five versions behind the current one (2.3.2 vs 7.0.0). Opening an issue at https://issues.qgis.org/issues might be a good start.